# iPhone: Masking an UIImage via touches

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimage, masking

before rolling up my sleeves and starting an own solution:

Is there already an approach for masking an image via touches?

Touches are marked yellow in my example:

[alt text http://img.skitch.com/20090628-nqmm3fsp7r8mcjg71wcm835kbi.jpg](http://img.skitch.com/20090628-nqmm3fsp7r8mcjg71wcm835kbi.jpg)

If there is no existing solution, I will try it to inspect Apple's 
drawing sample app to get some selections on the image.